# wkwebview not detecting onclick events swift

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

```
<div class="mb-3">
        <a href="https://www.somedomain.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.somedomain.com', '_system');">
          <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="position-relative" style="font-weight: 600;">
          SAVE</span>
           
        </button>
      </a>
      
    </div>
```

I am loading a webpage in my app through WKWebView. In this webpage we have button (HTML code above), when user taps on this button
`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {`
is never called.
Am I missing anything here?
I want to detect button tap & handle the action.

If I remove the onclick part from my html code, button tap is detected by iOS.

Comment: Don't have a button in an anchor or vice versa. Just style the link as a button

Comment: What difference would that make, same html code is working fine if I remove the onClick event.